# Printing CJK characters in title using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: printing, internationalization, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, chinese

I am trying to print Chinese characters title using ArcGIS javascript (3.10); however, the characters becomes a square block. I am able to see the characters in the JSON passed to the print task but the output is incorrect.

```
printTemplate.layoutOptions = {
  titleText = "some chinese characters"
}
```

Is there a way to set the print task to use Unicode characters?

Comment: Does the ArcGIS Server machine have Chinese language support?

Comment: @AamirSuleman, I installed the Chinese MUI on the server and am able to print the Chinese title on the server but still showing block characters on client machine.